# RPScreenRecorder - custom recording size

Tags: ios, swift, avassetwriterinput, rpscreenrecorder

I'm recording screen on iOS using RPScreenRecorder and it works fine, my question is , is there a way to set specific portion of the screen that I want to record instead of the entire screen?
So far I checked : AVAssetWriter, AVAudioSession, RPScreenRecorder but no luck.
thank you